# Windows store app prototyping

Tags: user-interface, windows-8, windows-store-apps, user-experience, prototyping

I have looked around here and the Internet in general but it seems this question hasn't received any answers yet. So, are there any good prototyping tools targeted specifically at Windows store app applications? Any tool would do as long as it has W8Metro layouts and components.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has [Expression Blend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229516.aspx) for prototyping, which is included in the Windows 8 development bundle.

Comment: Ah that's nice. Does it have Metro assets or is it just free hand prototyping ? (Oh, disregard my question, it has assets)

Comment: @DrunkenBeard If you meant UI components (e.g. `TextBlock`) by _assets_, everything you would expect is there.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2012 you can do [Storyboarding with PowerPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfs/hh409276%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). There's [a gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=RootCategory&f%5B0%5D.Value=StoryboardShapes&f%5B0%5D.Text=Storyboard%20Shapes) for controls, icons and stuff.